# JavaScript function works only when copied and pasted in Developer console but not from the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I am trying to write a Javascript function which when clicked on a button should get triggered. Problem is it works fine when I copy the Javascript function inside the developer's console but not from the code. Here is my code

velocity code:

```
  <body>

<table id="tablerows">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>with data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" ></td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>with data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3">
        <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>with data 3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



<button class="aui-button" id="test-button">Test</button>


<p id="out"></p>

</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
AJS.$('#test-button').click(function () {

        AJS.log("I am inside test button function")
        $('#out').text('');
        $('#rowclick2 tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
            // this = tr
            $tr = $(this);
            $('td', $tr).each(function() {
                // If you need to iterate the TD's
            });
            //get row values
            $('#out').append(this.id);
        });

    })
```

Comment: What is `AJS` and where in the HTML are you putting the script?

Comment: Can we see more of your html, mainly we want to see that you are including the javascript file. Are you seeing an error, can you print the error?

Comment: Probably [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660229/jquery-working-in-console-but-not-in-original-code) but there isn't enough code in the question to prove it.

Comment: Try to wrap the event listener inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Comment: @Quentin: AJS is the atlassian javascript framework

Comment: @blackmind: No console do not shows any error.

Comment: @Quentin: I  tried the script tag with $( document ).ready(function() it seems to be working but not when I call this from another JavaScript file.

Comment: I think the theory here is that your button doesn't exist at the time your code is called.  How about making it a delegated event? I'm not familiar with AJS but it looks similar to jQuery and the jQuery syntax would be like `$('body').on('click','#test-button',function(){...});`  the principle is you attach the listener to something higher up in the DOM that will be there (`body`) and then have the selector as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to external javacript file at end of body to ensure that your button already exists in the DOM.

Comment: I am already doing it by setting the context path for javascript file $webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("discovery")

Comment: Are you working with Asp.net? You can add a attribute, "onclick='yourFunctionHere();' at button.